# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Authorization')

Tags: reactjs

```
// code
import axios from 'axios';
import { getToken } from '../auth';

export const Base_url = 'http://localhost:8080';

export const myAxios = axios.create({
  baseUrl: Base_url,
});

export const privateAxios = axios.create({
  baseUrl: Base_url,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',

    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
});

//----post

privateAxios.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = getToken();
    console.log(token);
    if (token) {
      config.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      console.log(config);
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);
```

i am trying to post  with jwt token

I have tried to look for any possible solution everywhere but I am not getting any solution.  I get an error in the console **"TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Authorization')**",  why axios does not work.

Comment: Can u publish your project on codesandbox?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the token in `headers` directly:

```
privateAxios.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = getToken();
    console.log(token);
    if (token) {
      config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      console.log(config);
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);
```